# `npm root` gives a path to a directory that doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, npm

While in my `/Desktop` folder and I type in terminal `npm root` I get the path `/Users/Cathy/node_modules`.

However, `/Users/Cathy/node_modules` doesn't exist, so that path is incorrect.

If I'm in the `/Users` folder and I type in terminal `npm root' I get the path`/Users/node_modules`. That folder doesn't exist either.

I have no idea when that false path got set or how they got set. Or if the folder doesn't exist, why does `npm root` report it exists??

If I'm in a project I'm working on, `npm root` takes me to the right location where my modules live.

So, this is not causing me problems, but I want to understand what's going on. (I don't think I ever did an `npm install` within those folders which are closer to the root directory.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm root` prints the location of `node_module` folder effective for a particular location.

This means output is what will be used for installation. It does not mean if anything is installed there. It is for just for user support.

Comment: Ah, that's simple and neat - just appending `node_modules` to the path to the current working directory so people like me get reminded what the folder structure is. Thanks for the answer.